# IIF keyword is not working well Expression (RDLC Report)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am using the following expression in the RDLC report. 
But somehow, I am not able to use it very well, the values is returning "#Error" in the Report.

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value=0.00,CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%",CSTR((Fields!AUGTOT.Value/Fields!AUGNA.Value)*100) & "%")
```

but when I replace the false part with some string it works absolutely fine.

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00",CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%",
"REPLACED!")
```

All my fields in dataset is Decimal Type.i.e 72.88, 0.00 etc. I have tried to replace the false part with another IIF

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00",CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%",  IIF( Fields!AUGNA.Value <> "0.00",CSTR((Fields!AUGTOT.Value/Fields!AUGNA.Value)*100) & "%",nothing))
```

but that also doesn't work!

Please Help!
Imran.

Answer (score 0):

You have also put in double quotes the "test" part: `Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00"`...

If you look better at your posted code, you will see that in the second version, you have replaced not only the "false" part, but also the "test":

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00",CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%", "REPLACED!")
```

try this:

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00",CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%" ,CSTR((Fields!AUGTOT.Value/Fields!AUGNA.Value)*100) & "%")
```

Comment: Not Working! It says

Comment: pardon, there was a comma in plus.. try now

Comment: error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: Strill showing #Error in The Report. That is not correct.

Comment: try this...    =CSTR( IIf( Fields!AUGNA.Value=0.00,Fields!AUGTOT.Value, ((Fields!AUGTOT.Value / Fields!AUGNA.Value) * 100) )) & "%"

Comment: I just pasted it to the expression but still showing me #Error

Comment: I realized that true part works fine, if I replace the false part with string value like "Replaced".  But when put  calculation it doesn't work!

Comment: what says error? maybe it is an overflow or division by zero error due to decimal values division

Comment: It is not dividing by Zero because if does the result will be #infinity not #error.

Comment: The Value of AUGTOT=72.88 and AUGNA=0.00 offcourse if 72.88/0.00 means ERROR! but actually my IIF statment prevents since it is already checking it Fields!AUGNA.Value="0.00" then simply display the Fields!AUGTOT.Value

Comment: AUGNA is a decimal, so it isn't correct to compare it with a string.. you have convert it to a string with CSTR before.. CSTR(Fields!AUGNA.Value) = "0.00"

Comment: Can you write down the expression for me?

Comment: =IIf(CSTR(Fields!AUGNA.Value) = "0.00", CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%" ,CSTR((Fields!AUGTOT.Value/Fields!AUGNA.Value)*100) & "%")

Comment: :( NOT WORKING!

Comment: I suggest you to try a test of division of all your report data.. I think that if it is not a division by zero error, it is very likely an overflow error

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a custom divide function and call that function for division. 
 1. Right click on the Report area.
 2. Select Report Properties
 3. In the Properties Box, select Code and put the following code in the box.

```
  Public Function Divide(ByVal numerator As Double, ByVal denominator As Double) As Double
        If denominator = 0 Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return numerator / denominator 
        End If
    End Function
```

You expression to call this function would look something like the one below:

```
=IIf(Fields!AUGNA.Value=0.00,CSTR(Fields!AUGTOT.Value) & "%",CSTR(Code.Divide(Fields!AUGTOT.Value,Fields!AUGNA.Value)*100) & "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but if others get here with a similar problem...

It appears that the **IIf** statement evaluates both branches and then tests the expression for true / false. Thus, if you have a function or expression in one of the branches that throws an error (such as divide by zero), the whole thing returns **#Error**.
This also seems to be true for Switch statements
The only way I have found around this is to create a custom function in the Report Code section, send it the required parameters and let it do the comparison and return the correct value.